# dynamic_matchers.rb:55:in `method_missing': undefined method `migration_error=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, windows, activerecord, scaffold

I'm on Windows. Ruby v.1.9.3p392 / Rails v. 3.2.13 - This is the demo_app project from the 2nd chapter of Michael Hart's Ruby on Rails Tutorial.

This error comes up when I issue '**rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string**'  Any idea how to fix this?

```
C:\ruby\rails_projects\demo_app>rails generate scaffold User name:string email:s
tring
      invoke  active_record
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/act
ive_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:55:in `method_missing': undefined method `migrati
on_error=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3
.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:66:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3
.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:65:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3
.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:65:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3
.2.13/lib/active_record/base.rb:720:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/generators/named_base.rb:166:in `pluralize_table_names?'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/generators/named_base.rb:114:in `table_name'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3
.2.13/lib/rails/generators/active_record/model/model_generator.rb:17:in `create_
migration_file'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `block in invoke_all'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `map'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_all'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/group.rb:233:in `dispatch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:109:in `invoke'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/group.rb:278:in `block in _invoke_for_class_method'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/shell.rb:74:in `with_padding'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/group.rb:267:in `_invoke_for_class_method'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/group.rb:150:in `_invoke_from_option_orm'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `block in invoke_all'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `map'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_all'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/group.rb:233:in `dispatch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/li
b/thor/base.rb:439:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/generators.rb:171:in `invoke'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/commands/generate.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/commands.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

dynamic_matchers.rb

```
module ActiveRecord
  module DynamicMatchers
    def respond_to?(method_id, include_private = false)
      if match = DynamicFinderMatch.match(method_id)
        return true if all_attributes_exists?(match.attribute_names)
      elsif match = DynamicScopeMatch.match(method_id)
        return true if all_attributes_exists?(match.attribute_names)
      end

      super
    end

    private

    # Enables dynamic finders like <tt>User.find_by_user_name(user_name)</tt> and
    # <tt>User.scoped_by_user_name(user_name). Refer to Dynamic attribute-based finders
    # section at the top of this file for more detailed information.
    #
    # It's even possible to use all the additional parameters to +find+. For example, the
    # full interface for +find_all_by_amount+ is actually <tt>find_all_by_amount(amount, options)</tt>.
    #
    # Each dynamic finder using <tt>scoped_by_*</tt> is also defined in the class after it
    # is first invoked, so that future attempts to use it do not run through method_missing.
    def method_missing(method_id, *arguments, &block)
      if match = (DynamicFinderMatch.match(method_id) || DynamicScopeMatch.match(method_id))
        attribute_names = match.attribute_names
        super unless all_attributes_exists?(attribute_names)
        if !(match.is_a?(DynamicFinderMatch) && match.instantiator? && arguments.first.is_a?(Hash)) && arguments.size < attribute_names.size
          method_trace = "#{__FILE__}:#{__LINE__}:in `#{method_id}'"
          backtrace = [method_trace] + caller
          raise ArgumentError, "wrong number of arguments (#{arguments.size} for #{attribute_names.size})", backtrace
        end
        if match.respond_to?(:scope?) && match.scope?
          self.class_eval <<-METHOD, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
            def self.#{method_id}(*args)                                    # def self.scoped_by_user_name_and_password(*args)
              attributes = Hash[[:#{attribute_names.join(',:')}].zip(args)] #   attributes = Hash[[:user_name, :password].zip(args)]
                                                                            #
              scoped(:conditions => attributes)                             #   scoped(:conditions => attributes)
            end                                                             # end
          METHOD
          send(method_id, *arguments)
        elsif match.finder?
          options = if arguments.length > attribute_names.size
                      arguments.extract_options!
                    else
                      {}
                    end

          relation = options.any? ? scoped(options) : scoped
          relation.send :find_by_attributes, match, attribute_names, *arguments, &block
        elsif match.instantiator?
          scoped.send :find_or_instantiator_by_attributes, match, attribute_names, *arguments, &block
        end
      else
        super
      end
    end

    # Similar in purpose to +expand_hash_conditions_for_aggregates+.
    def expand_attribute_names_for_aggregates(attribute_names)
      attribute_names.map { |attribute_name|
        unless (aggregation = reflect_on_aggregation(attribute_name.to_sym)).nil?
          aggregate_mapping(aggregation).map do |field_attr, _|
            field_attr.to_sym
          end
        else
          attribute_name.to_sym
        end
      }.flatten
    end

    def all_attributes_exists?(attribute_names)
      (expand_attribute_names_for_aggregates(attribute_names) -
       column_methods_hash.keys).empty?
    end

    def aggregate_mapping(reflection)
      mapping = reflection.options[:mapping] || [reflection.name, reflection.name]
      mapping.first.is_a?(Array) ? mapping : [mapping]
    end


  end
end
```

Answer (score 7):

ok, so someone else was able to find the solution to this problem and i'll share it here in case it comes up for someone else.

Apparently, the app I was creating was generating an old rails version even though my rails versions was set to a recent one. 3.2.13

Therefore my config/application.rb file was completely different than a rails 3.2.13 version. After the application.rb file was replaced. The errors were fixed.

To avoid this error, you can either use rvm or pik if you're a windows user to control your current version. You can specify your rails version when creating a new app 'rails *3.2.13* your_app', or uninstall all rails versions and just install the one you need:

**gem uninstall rails**
-choose all versions

**gem install rails --version '= 3.2.13'**

Comment: actually, it should be 'rails new demo_app 3.2.13' to specify a rails version for an app if needed.

Comment: sorry, this is the correct command 'rails _3.2.13_ new newappname'

Comment: umm, yea that version specification is still wrong. lol but its not needed. rails will install the latest by default ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the advice (+1), I had the same problem...

Created the app initially with an older version of rails and bumped it to the lastest (3.2.13) which broke my devise stuff..

All that was needed was to add `require "rails/all"` to the top of `config/application.rb`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that was complaining about an undefined method: '  has_many'. I spent a while fiddling with ruby and rails versions and gems before realizing the problem... the extra spaces before has_many!

I had copied old code from another place (Evernote, which uses all sorts of weird formatting) and didn't realize the whitespace details could mess things up like that. Deleting the spaces and putting them back in manually fixed the problem.

(This isn't really an answer to the original question, but my searches led me here and might lead others here.)