# I can't make Active Record simple query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

This:

```
User.where 'id < ?', 5
```

fails with this message:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `join' for #<Class:0x007fa4c9b5a598>
```

When I try:

```
User.where 'id < 5'
```

it works.

In another project:

```
User.where 'id < ?', 5
```

works.

Where could be my problem?

## Update

I could solve the problem but commenting a gem:

```
# gem 'cancan'
```

### Working flow

Then when I run console, I get:

```
load error: ~/.irbrc
NameError: uninitialized constant ApplicationController::CanCan
```

And my simple query works.

### Not working flow

Then I comment CanCan part of application controller and console starts without problems, but when I try my simple query it fails with the same error.

### What I am trying now

Searching for `join` in `~/.irbrc`, I got several results. But I am not sure of what I am doing.

Where could be my problem?

Comment: Can you post your model? There may be some clues in the scopes/associations.

Comment: I agree. It sounds like a default scope of some sort.

Comment: Try searching for `join` in your model code. If you find it replace it with `joins`.

Comment: Is a legacy code, and I can't share it, I signed a contract, there is no `scope`, neither `join` words, neither class methods.

Comment: It fails in the same line as this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16364347/dynamic-matchers-rb55in-method-missing-undefined-method-migration-error

Comment: I commented all code in user model, and same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this snippet in my `~/.irbrc`

```
203   # instead of User.find(...) you can do user(...)
204   #   without arguments it only returns the model class
205   #   based on http://www.clarkware.com/blog/2007/09/03/console-shortcut
206 #  Dir.glob( File.join(Dir.pwd, *%w<app models ** *.rb>) ).map { |file_name|
207 #    table_name = File.basename(file_name).split('.')[0..-2].join
```

I commented all the block and now it works. Well, I copied that file and never have understood it.

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer to your question, but I personally try to use as little straight SQL as possible in my code.

Check out the squeel gem, which will help with this, especially this kind of query.
https://github.com/ernie/squeel

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, will take that into account.