# Error when execute rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am completely newby in Ruby and I am following the tutorial made by Michael Hartl.
In Chapter 2, Page 49, the book indicates:

```
rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
```

After execute this, the application shows:

```
    C:\demo_app>rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
C:/demo_app/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefine
d method `configure' for #<DemoApp::Application:0x35d3d98> (NoMethodError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/engine.rb:571:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
        from C:/demo_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/commands.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I have already use bundle install, bundle update, installed new (and old) version of gems... 
Could someone oriented me about what is wrong?
Or a way to avoid this mistake in order to follow with the next steps.

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22977051/error-launching-rails-server-undefined-method-configure

Comment: Can you please post your `config/environments/development.rb` and the Rails version you use.

Comment: @jkmr You are right, I followed the step and I solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bundle exec rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesnt work.... `C:\demo_app>bundle exec rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]`

Options:....

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
The steps were:

1. Correct the file `development.rb` including in the first line `DemoApp::Application.configure do`
2. Later I found another problem when I tried to execute `rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string`.
   The description of the problem was:
   C:\demo_app>rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
         invoke  active_record
   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/acti
   ve_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:50:in `method_missing': undefined method`migratio
   n_error=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
3. Finally, I deleting the following line in `config/environments/development.rb`:
   `config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load`

I used a mix between the next answers:

- [rake aborted! undefined method `migration_error=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000712/rake-aborted-undefined-method-migration-error-for-activerecordbaseclass)
- [Error launching Rails server: undefined method 'configure'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22977051/error-launching-rails-server-undefined-method-configure)